# Classic ASP Request.Form removes spaces?

Tags: forms, asp-classic, request

I'm trying to figure this oddity out... in classic ASP i seem to be losing spaces in Request.Form values...

ie, Request.Form("json") is

```
{"project":{"...","administrator":"AlexGorbatchev",
"anonymousViewUrl":null,"assets":[],"availableFrom":"6/10/20104:15PM"...
```

However, CStr(Request.Form) is

```
json={"project":{"__type":"...":"Alex Gorbatchev",
"anonymousViewUrl":null,"assets":[],"availableFrom":"6/10/2010 4:15 PM"...
```

Here's the entire code :)

```
<%@ language="VBSCRIPT"%>
<%
Response.Write(CStr(Request.Form("json")))
Response.Write(CStr(Request.Form))
%>
```

Somebody please tell me I haven't lost all my marbles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aaand I found the problem 5 minutes after... as usual :) posted values need to be url encoded.