# asp classic: request.form data has no spaces

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I'm sending post data using jquery, but when I retrieve it in asp all the spaces have been removed.

[Classic ASP Request.Form removes spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018548/classic-asp-request-form-removes-spaces)

I found that question, but I'm not sure what he meant by url encode.

Here is my jquery:

```
var dataString = 'name='+$("#name").val()+'&email='+$("#email").val()+'&note='+$("#note").val();


                    $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "asp_mail.asp",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  

                         $("p#mail-prompt").html("The message was successfully sent.");
                         $("div#the-prompt").slideDown();


   }  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a string as data, jQuery assumes that you have encoded the data correctly, but you haven't encoded the values. Use an object instead, so that jQuery encodes the values:

```
var dataObject = {
  name: $("#name").val(),
  email: $("#email").val(),
  note: $("#note").val()
};
```